# Running Time of Nested Loops

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I am sure the running time of this nested loop is O(N*log(N)). The running time of the inner loop is log(N) and the outher loop is N.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  for (int j = 1; j <= i; j *= 2) { 
  }
}
```

In the inner Loop what if I change `j *= 2` to `j *= 3`. How is the result going to change in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will still be logarithmic.  However, it will be scaled by a constant factor (which is irrelevant in Big O analysis).

The effect is that the base of the logarithm changes (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base).

Comment: log(N) normally is log10^N. So you mean its going to be log3^N ?

Comment: The original is log_2 (N).  The new one will be log_3(n).  Again, this is irrelevant in Big O analysis.  It will still be log(n).

Answer (score 3):

@Kevin is completely right, but I thought I would show some experimental results.  You can easily test this out by creating a counter that gets incremented inside each inner loop iteration and running for different values of N.  Then a fit can be made of the form `time = a * N * log(N)`.  For the case `j *= 2`, we get a coefficient `a = 1.28`.  For `j *= 3`, we get `a = 0.839`.

[image]

I generated this figure using the MATLAB script below:

```
clear
clc
close all

nmin = 10;
nmax = 1000;

count1 = zeros(nmax - nmin + 1, 1);

for n = nmin: nmax

    k = 0;
    for i = 0: n - 1
        j = 1;
        while (j <= i)
            j = j * 2;
            k = k + 1;
        end
    end

    count1(n - nmin + 1) = k;

end

ns = (nmin: nmax)';

figure
hold on
plot(ns, count1, '--')

a1 = mean(count1 ./ (ns .* log(ns)))

fit1 = a1 * ns .* log(ns);
plot(ns, fit1)

%%

count2 = zeros(nmax - nmin + 1, 1);

for n = nmin: nmax

    k = 0;
    for i = 0: n - 1
        j = 1;
        while (j <= i)
            j = j * 3;
            k = k + 1;
        end
    end

    count2(n - nmin + 1) = k;

end

ns = (nmin: nmax)';

plot(ns, count2, '-.')

a2 = mean(count2 ./ (ns .* log(ns)))

fit2 = a2 * ns .* log(ns);
plot(ns, fit2)

xlabel('N')
ylabel('Time complexity')
legend('j *= 2', 'j *= 2 fit', 'j *= 3', 'j *= 3 fit', 'Location', 'NorthWest')
```

Answer (score 0):

----------[ j = 2 * j ] for j < i:-------------

```
j = 2*1 = 2 =>2^1
    2*2 = 4 =>2^2
    2*4 = 8 =>2^3
............. 2^k = n say n==i
if log applied on both side 2^k = n 
log(2^k) = logn
k = log_2(N) where 2 is the base
```

----------[ j = 3 * j ] for j < i:-------------

```
j = 3*1 = 3  =>3^1
    3*3 = 9  =>3^2
    3*9 = 27 =>2^3
.............loop stop when 3^k = n say n==i
if log applied on both side 3^k = n 
log(3^k) = logn
k = log_3(N) where 3 is the base
```